# Custom AWS AMI Swap and Temp Folder

Tags: amazon-ec2, ec2-ami

I want to create an AMI. This AMI should mount the ephemeral storage of my instances on startup and create a `swap file` and a folder for `/tmp`

What I'm currently doing is after I booted to run a couple of commands:

```
sudo mkdir /media/ephemeral1/
sudo mount /dev/xvdc /media/ephemeral1/
sudo mkdir /media/ephemeral1/temp
sudo mount -B /tmp /media/ephemeral1/temp
```

and: (xvdb is alway auto-mounted at /media/ephemeral0/ ?)

```
sudo /bin/dd if=/dev/zero of=/media/ephemeral0/swap.1 bs=1M count=4096
sudo /sbin/mkswap /media/ephemeral0/swap.1
sudo chmod 600 /media/ephemeral0/swap.1
sudo /sbin/swapon /media/ephemeral0/swap.1
```

do I just add all of this to my `~/.bashrc` or what is the correct way to solve this. At the end I want an AMI that I can slap on a Instance with ephemeral storage and just get both a `temp dir` and a `swap`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, .bash_rc is the wrong place for this because it will run each time Bash is launched. You may want to look at using user data on launch. Since you're moving these to ephemeral storage you must keep in mind that ephemeral storage can be different per instance type and class. Baking this type of change into an AMI directly is not possible since AMIs must be EBS backed. Therefore, your best option is to use user data as outlined below -

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/user-data.html

Comment: Thanks, yes I understand that the ephemeral storage varies from instance type to instances type. What I did not mention was that the AMI will be for a specific instance (c3.2xlarge). Will the already mounted devices (xvdb/xvdc) differ from c3.2xlarge instance to c3.2xlarge instance?

Comment: No but you would need to handle this via user data like is detailed in the answer.

Comment: *"Baking this type of change into an AMI directly is not possible since AMIs must be EBS backed"* is a non-sequitur, as well as inaccurate.  An instance store AMI is not EBS backed, of course... and with an EBS-backed AMI this can all be baked in to be executed on startup using the metadata service (not user-data) to discover the device names of the ephemeral disks.